# Limitar endereço de IP

Tags: php, geolocalização

estou com um projeto de um supermercado online e meu cliente deseja que apenas possam fazer os pedidos aqueles que residirem dentro da cidade na qual ele possui este supermercado.
Ele tem problemas pois já tem esse supermercado usando opencart e sempre aparece um pedido de fora da cidade e até mesmo fora do estado.
Existe alguma forma de limitar para que somente os Endereços de IP que estão dentro da cidade possam efetuar suas compras?

Comment: O problema de usar o IP e que muitas vezes podem emular o IP de outra cidade ou pais, nesse seu caso não usa o CEP para fazer o pedido? Acho que seria o caminho menos sofrivel

Comment: Boa ideia amigo

Comment: Já tive problemas com aplicações que pensavam que eu estava nos Estados Unidos sendo que estava em São Paulo. Isso porque a rede que eu usava estava sendo tunelada para lá (sim, isso era intencional) antes de retornar ao Brasil.

Comment: @VictorStafusa se for uma coisa que dá pra mandar por carta ainda vai, o duro é se for algo que pesa uma... _tunelada_ :P

Comment: É complicado isso. Ip é estranho eu uso uma adsl com ip não fixo e muitos sites especialisados em análise de ips enxergam a minha localização que é em Uberlândia em vários locais de atuação da rede do Grupo Algar Telecom como Mato Grosso, Goiás ou qualquer outra cidade. Como os caras disseram um jeito certo é perguntar o cep antes ou antes de fechar o carrinho de compras e nesse momento avisar caso ele não tenha lido as mensagens no site. É muito comum no Brasil se deparar com pessoas que não leem o site e só enxergam o que querem e desconsideram tudo mais a sua volta.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que limitar por Ips não é uma boa ideia. Talvez a melhor solução seja deixar claro no layout a entrega somente na cidade e usar algum tipo de filtro por CEP. Se o CEP de entrega estiver fora da área de cobertura o sistema avisa que não será possível concluir o pedido.

Procure descobrir qual é o "range" de CEPs da cidade.

Comment: De fato, farei isso.

Comment: Marque a resposta